# Canvas script does not output anything

Tags: javascript, canvas

From my point of view I'm doing anything the right way. I begin my script when the pages loads, my syntax is OK. The problem I suppose is that the init function doesn't load, could anybody please point out where I commit my failure?

```
var canvas;
    var ctx;
    var x = 75;
    var y = 50;
    var r = 100;
    var width = 400;
    var height = 300;
    var drag = false;

    addEventListener("load",windowLoaded,false);

    function windowLoaded(){
        init();
        console.log("beertje");
    }

    function init() {
     canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
     ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
     return setInterval(Circle, 10);
     canvas.onmousedown = myDown;
     canvas.onmouseup = myUp;
     console.log("beertje");


    }

    function Circle(x,y,r) {
     ctx.beginPath();
     ctx.arc(x,y,r,0,Math.PI,true);
     ctx.closePath();
     ctx.fill();
     }

     function draw() {
     clear();
     arc(x,y,r,0,Math.PI,true);
     ctx.fillStyle = "#444444";
     arc(x - 15, y - 15, r, 0, Math.PI, true);
    }

    function myMove(e){
     if (drag){
      x = e.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft;
      y = e.pageY - canvas.offsetTop;
     }
    }

    function myDown(e){
     if (e.pageX < x + 15 + canvas.offsetLeft && e.pageX > x - 15 +
     canvas.offsetLeft && e.pageY < y + 15 + canvas.offsetTop &&
     e.pageY > y -15 + canvas.offsetTop){
      x = e.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft;
      y = e.pageY - canvas.offsetTop;
      drag = true;
      canvas.onmousemove = myMove;
     }
    }

    function myUp(){
     drag = false;
     canvas.onmousemove = null;
    }
```

Comment: `Circle` function takes three arguments, but you're not passing any: `setInterval(Circle, 10);`. Also both eventhandlers are never assigned, `return...` will cut the execution of `init()`.

Answer (score 1):

The first problem in the code is the `setInterval()`, which calls `Circle()` without arguments. Nevertheless there are global `x`, `y` and `r`, those are not defined inside `Circle()`, since its arguments with the same name will shadow globals. ([Function scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#Function_scope))

However, you can pass those global values to `Circle()` like this:

```
 return setInterval(function () {
            Circle(x, y, r);
        }, 10);
```

But this is very memory consuming code, since the same circle is drawn 100 times per second, there will be tons of circles on the screen just in few minutes... I'd suggest, that you'd draw the circle in eventhandlers only, without any timer.

Also returning this interval to nowhere is unnecessary (unless this is only a part of your code, and there is a receiver in `windowLoaded()`).

Due to the "extra" `return`, eventhandler assigments in `init()` are useless, since this `return` above will move the execution back to the `windowLoaded()`. Hence the rest of the function will never be executed. I'd suggest you to move either the `return` (useless at the moment) or the whole line, to the end of the function.